# HowTo longtime monitor the amount of used and open ports and their state (like Fin_wait2, time_wait, eg.)?

Tags: networking, server

**I'd like to refind a tool I have used before to pinpoint problems with the port usage of a system.** It was a small tool (small like using almost no resources) with it's own webpage-server, that showed the real time and also statistical usage (hour/day/week/month) of all the ports and their states. I think it was written in python, but I'm not 100% sure.

**The reason I'm looking for this tool:** A tcp connection always waits for 1 minute until it's completly closed, after the final data has been exchanged. **It's not about WHAT (program, service) is hitting the box, but how much traffic is hitting the box and hence how much ports are open, especially how much are in fin_wait.**

**What I'm not looking for: I'm familiar with netstat, but I don't think that this is the right tool to do long term statistics** as I have about 30 systems to worry about. But proof me wrong, if you have a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it really took me a while to find it with the right search terms in Google.
The tool is called darkstat. You can install it via apt.

```
apt install darkstat
```